# How to pass model as Multipart form data to web api and return Json as result

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am need to pass model data in  Multi part form data format, and the api should in Json format.

I tried creating a custom media type formatter but it is not good.

I tried to replicate code in [this link](http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/23/web-api-generic-mediatypeformatter-for-file-upload/). But it servers a different requirement. Basically I only want to post model data in multi part form data.

I want to post model data in multi part form data and return the result as Json

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void Post(ViewModel value)
```

Thanks in Advance
Sudheer

Comment: Can you please post some code of your media type formatter? What response do you get when you try and post some data?

Comment: Updated in question @AnishPatel

Comment: Are you saying you only want the post a json object to your web api controller and that you do not want to upload a file along with this json object? Can you post some code of your controller to give me a better idea of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Does the `Content-Type` have to be `multipart/form-data`? If you intend to return the result as `application/json` can the request not also send the data as `application/json`?

Comment: Forget about the result for now, At least I should be able to receive Multi form data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83362/discussion-between-anish-patel-and-kokirala-sudheer).